# BeautifulSoup - name of link

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have this html page:

```
<ul class="quicklinks">
<li class="subnav_item_main">
<a href="action.html">Action
</a> </li>
<li class="subnav_item_main">
<a href="adventure.html">Adventure
</a> </li>..............
```

I succeeded inserting all the links to a list:

```
soup=load_soup_object(html_file_name)
mtag=soup.find("ul", attrs={"class" : "quicklinks"})
link_to_pages=[t['href'] for t in mtag.findAll("a")]
```

How can I insert the categories names as well?
Like so: [Action, Adventure........]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `text` attribute:

```
category_names = [tag.text for tag in mtag.find_all('a')]
```